# How to block a specific process to internet access?

Tags: windows-7, internet, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent a file from accessing the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/131365/how-to-prevent-a-file-from-accessing-the-internet)

How can I block internet access for a specific `process` on `windows 7`?

Note: The running process is not necessarily an installed software. And I don't know which specific ports it will be using.

For example:
Installation process of a software.

What I want to achieve is to pick a process from `Task Manager`, and just block it from all internet activity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is a firewall and you have to set its defaults to disallow any outgoing connection unless explicitly allowed.

There's no easy way for a program to integrate with Task Manager, so you either have to answer a prompt given by the firewall when a program tries to access the net or use the firewall's built-in list of processes (if any).