# How to Block a single Program (Or a File) that using Internet?

Tags: internet, connection, process

There are several Programs, Files and Process that use the internet to share their status. They are using consuming too much bandwidth.

How can I stop them from using Internet Connection in Windows OS?

Comment: You can block them in firewall

Comment: @Voitcus : So I haven't to set Which ports they using, just set the program as Blocked. Is it?  so how can i stop the process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I block a program from accessing the Internet?](http://superuser.com/questions/363540/how-can-i-block-a-program-from-accessing-the-internet), http://superuser.com/questions/131365/how-to-prevent-a-file-from-accessing-the-internet, http://superuser.com/questions/15425/restrict-programs-from-accessing-the-internet

Comment: Also worth wondering, if these programs work in a way you do not like, try either configuring them, or uninstalling them

Comment: @AthomSfere : The programs have no any Configuring settings because they are not Official Programs.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Voitcus pointed out in comment *(IMHO that should be answer not comment)* the easiest way would be to block them in your firewall.

Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Allow app to access net -> Pick your application's exe file -> Deny both

(I have Polish version of Windows, so the command may have a litle other names)

Comment: Is there a method to block a Process with name of that which have move to different locations?

Comment: AFAIK if the process manifest does not change (I mean if it isn't self-modyfing, or being recompiled, or does not change in any other crazy way) than firewall will block the exe not matter the location (the original location is used only for checking manifest)

Comment: It is not possible in system Vista firewall -- you need to give absolute path to the process. Consider using second party FW, some of them are freeware.

Comment: @Voitcus AFAIK you're not right - you need absolute path only to init blockade, after then the Firewall will check application manifest

Comment: Well, maybe, I haven't tested it so deeply.

Answer (score 1):

As PiotrK pointed out use a firewall. On Windows XP or newer you can use built-in firewall (you require administrator privileges). You can set which application has which rights. In any time you can tick or untick rule for this application to (de)activate blocking.

For older Windows systems there are freeware (usually for non-commercial use) firewalls, some of them having large configuration options (better rules than this of Windows).

It is advised not to use two firewalls at the same time, so first turn off your system one.